# Re-project rotated object in an image

Tags: image, image-processing, geometry, transformation, homography

I have a rotated (3D) rectangle object in real-world and I'm trying to re-project this object into the image.

Suppose we have the following parameters:

- The four corners of the rectangle in real-world and the image `[(xw1, yw1,zw1) , (xw2, yw2,zw2) , (xw3, yw3,zw3) , (xw4, yw4,zw4) ] ; [(x1, y1) , (x2, y2) , (x3, y3) , (x4, y4) ]`.
- The distance between the camera and the object (e.g. `D`).
- Intrinsic camera parameters (focal length and principle point).
- Extrinsic camera parameters (the rotation matrix `R (3x3)` and the translation matrix `t (3x1)`).
- The 3D surface normal vector (`<v1; v2; v3>`) of the rectangle object with respect to the camera.
- Check this image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYKYb.jpg)

How can we re-project the rectangle from the "real world" to the image using the given information above. So, the object in image must look like the real world (oriented).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [compute a projective transformation from the images of four points](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416). So the first point you mentioned, the coordinates of the rectangle in world and image coordinates, is sufficient.

Comment: I'm not trying to calculate the projections matrix here. Because I already have the projection matrix which transform from real-world to image plane.
I'm trying to represent the orientated object in the 2D image according to the surface normal vector `<v1; v2; v3>`.  
During the transformation from 3D to 2D you are losing the depth information.But the 2D image it may look like a 3D. As summary,I'm trying to represent the object in the 2D image and showing the direction of the orientation
I'm not sure how we can connect between the projection matrix with the surface normal vector of the object.

Comment: if you look to this image, it's look like a 3D but it's 2D. [image](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUD3tYAJX_5bLI0d3_OjL3Kh2FXLiS4GWFuEWqLblh204Z-rX9PA)

Comment: @Omar14: I must confess I still don't see exactly what you mean. But please note that I'm talking about the matrix of a projective transformation, i.e. a homography, not about the matrix of a projection. In your railroad image, that could be used to e.g. make the tracks parallel again, as they would appear from straight above, which is my understanding of what you mean by reprojection. It is purely 2D to 2D.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry if my question was not clear!. maybe because I'm little bit confused. But basically, imagine we have an object in real-world
and I have the 3D orientation of this object with respect to camera (represented by the surface normal vector). I need to plot this object in 2D image and 
make it look like a 3D. Check this image: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dYKYb.jpg). The second image shows exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Omar14: I saw this image. And again I'd use a homography defined by 4 points. Just to clarify: your object is a plane rectangle, you have an image of what it looks like, and you have the corner coordinates in a second scene, and you want to draw it correctly into that second scene. Is this correct? You can do [fun things](http://youtu.be/gqWJQgOMNNw) with this kind of transformation, including correctly embedding planar stuff into a planar image of a 3d scene.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I think I have to read more about homography. But Is the concept of applying the homography on a rectangle same as on an ellipse? for example taking some of ellipse edge points.

Comment: Do you need to include perspective?  With the example you gave, of a solid rectangle, perspectinve won't matter.  But on a more detailed image, projecting that image to 4 two-dimensional points is not exactly the same as projecting that image into 4 three-dimensional points, then projecting the result into 2D.  Old graphics engines used to treat them the same.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping#Perspective_correctness

Comment: @Omar14: You can also map ellipses, but the map won't be uniquely defined by knowing the two ellipses. You still have three real degrees of freedom. Choosing “edge points” would be one possibility, but not neccessarily the correct one. For details on this, see [this spin-off question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/654275/35416) I just wrote.

Comment: @MvG: I noted from your solution and using the homograph to represent the object in the image; that you ignore the information about the surface normal vector.
Where is the main idea here is using this information of the 3D orientation represented by the surface normal vector to 
represent the object in the 2D image and make it look like 3D.
I don't know if that possible or not!!

Comment: @Omar14: I'm aware that I ignore a lot of information: surface normal, camera parameters, and so on. But if your corner points are correct, then they already must match all the rest. There is only one homography between two planar quadrilaterals, so the rest of the information is either superfluous or inconsistent with that. I assumed the former.

Comment: @MvG: So the homograph will not solve my problem. Because I have two normal vector for the same object (same position).
and I need to show how is the object looks like in the 2D image for both orientation. What do you think?

Comment: @Omar14: Too bad we can't chat, but you need 20 rep for this. I think I still don't understand your question correctly. Perhaps you can be more specific. What is your object, what is the image you have, what exactly do you mean by “look like the real world”?

Comment: @MvG: Well, imagine you have an object in real-world. And I give you two possible 3D orientation of this object with respect to the camera. suppose `v1 = [0;0;1]` and `v2 = [0.866; 0; 0.5]`.let us say the object is a rectangle.  Then I asked you to project this rectangle into 2D image twice, first according v1 orientation and second is v2 orientation. suppose you have the information that I mentioned in the question above. So at the end, the projection of the rectangle must shows the orientation of v1 and v2. So, we will show the rectangle twice in the image according to their orientations.

Comment: @MvG: Again simply, We have the following information and we need to represent the rectangle object in 2D image:
The 3D surface normal vector `(<vx; vy; vz>)` of the rectangle object with respect to the camera, camera parameters,
distance between the camera and the object, and the location of the object with respect to camera.

Comment: @Omar14: Where do the corner points come from? I would assume that the corner points in the image are the result of computing how the normal vector affects the projected position. So the normal vector information is already incorporated in the corner point positions. I don't see this reflected in your description, though.

Comment: @MvG: for now, you can assume that I measured the corners using ruler. I measured the distance of each corner to camera frame. Assume the rotated object on the floor and the camera on the ceil. Then we measure the distance from each corner to the camera. We can say: `c1 (0,0,70), c2(10,0,70), c3(0,-10,75), c4(-10,-10,75)`.

Comment: @Omar14: In your question, you had 2D coordinates, now you speak about distances which would be scalar quantities, but give an example with 3D coordinates. This is inconsistent.

Comment: @MvG: I indicated in the question that the object in the real-world and the normal to the surface is know by `<vx;vy,vz>`. And I'm trying to project this object in 2D image. sorry for any confusion!.